# Edit CSS of React Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-component

I am using a react component [react-awesome-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-modal) as follows.

```
<Modal visible={this.state.visible}  width="850" height="450" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}>
```

Now I want to add a new style `overflow-y:scroll` to this Modal component.

I tried doing this, but it didn't worked:

```
<Modal visible={this.state.visible}  style={{"overflow-y":"scroll"}} width="850" height="450" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}>
```

Is there any way I can apply the property to this component.

PS: I had tried applying this property using chrome Devtool(Inspect element). In that, I am able to see the complete CSS that is used for this component, so I was able to update it easily (see the last line in the image)

[image]

Comment: did you try without the curly brackets? style="overflow-y":"scroll".

Comment: Getting error `Identifier expected.` brackets are necessary.

Comment: You could try use ref to get the DOM of component `<Modal>`, then change the style of the DOM.

Comment: Fyi this component is deprecated: http://shibe97.github.io/react-awesome-modal/. Also, looks like `<Modal>`'s implementation does not render your `style` prop.

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu Can you please throw light on how to get the DOM of any component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try insert a div element under `<Modal />` , then set the style of this div:

```
<Modal visible={this.state.visible} width="400" height="300" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}>
  <div style={{overflowY:"scroll", height:"300px"}}>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Some Contents</p>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>Close</a>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

If solution above doesn't work, then try creatRef, get DOM of `<Modal />`, and change the style of `<Modal />`: (React version must be newer than 16.3)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-awesome-modal';

class Test extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.modalRef = React.createRef()  //create Ref to get DOM
   }

  componentDidMount(){
       this.modalRef.current.style.overflowY = "scroll"   //change style of Modal DOM
  }

   render() {

       return (
          <div>
             <Modal visible={this.state.visible} width="400" height="300" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()} ref={this.modalRef}>
                <div>
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    <p>Some Contents</p>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>Close</a>
                </div>
             </Modal>
          </div>
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked like a charm. Didn't tried the second approach. Thanks a lot!!!